# LINQ Check if database column's value is in a List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a table called `documents` like this:

```
ID DocumentName Name
1 Test1.txt Alan
2 Test2.txt Alan
3 Test3.txt Jane
4 Test4.txt Alan
5 Test5.txt Bob
6 Test6.txt Bob
7 Test7.txt Jane
```

And I want to filter using LINQ to only show those rows from that table with the names provided by a list e.g:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("Alan");
names.Add("Bob");
```

should only show:

```
ID DocumentName Name
1 Test1.txt Alan
2 Test2.txt Alan
4 Test4.txt Alan
5 Test5.txt Bob
6 Test6.txt Bob
```

What I have tried:

```
var filteredDatabase = db.document =
    .Where(a => a.Name.Intersect(names).Any());
```

This does not work, and the error says:

> CS1929 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Intersect' and the
>   best extension method overload
>   'Queryable.Intersect(IQueryable, IEnumerable)'
>   requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

I have also tried:

```
var filteredDatabase = db.document =
    .Where(a => a.Name.Any(x => names.Contains(x));
```

This does also not work, and the error says:

> cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'.

Any idea where I am going wrong in this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contains` works this way

```
var filteredDatabase = db.document.Where(a => names.Contains(a.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains`:

```
var filteredDatabase = db.document
    .Where(a => names.Contains(a.Name));
```

This should be supported by all LINQ providers. You could also use `Join` if the `List<string>` doesn't contain duplicates. This works only in Linq-To-Objects:

```
var filteredDocuments = from doc in documents // documents is f.e. List<CustomType>
                        join name in names
                        on doc.Name equals name
                        select doc;
```

If the list contains duplicates you get repeating documents.